# How to fix output file not breaking output line by line?

Tags: python, regex, shell

I am writing a Python script to read in a file, read through that file line by line and parse out data from that file to another text file via user command line argument. Right now, I am able to read the input file line by line and parse out the data via command line argument. However, the output file that I am trying to write to print all in one line rather than break the output line by line.

temp.log:

```
06 May 19 03:40:35 3 abCodeClearTrap Error Clear Trap (agent: 12367a12,
chassis:12367a12, ErrIdText: ERROR ID TEXT, csssi: EXTIFG, clearedID:
0x089088394)

06 May 19 03:44:35 3 abCodeErrorTrap Error Trap (agent: 12368a15, chassis:
12368a15, ErrIdText: Skip this item, csssi: SSRSSR, clearedID:
0x089088394)
```

My code:

```
import re, sys

with open('temp.log') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt') as o:

    data = []
    for line in lines:
       if 'date' in sys.argv:
           try:
              date = re.match(r'\date{2} \w+ \date{2}', line).group()
              row.append(date)
           except:
              date = 'date'
       if 'agent' in sys.argv:
           try:
              agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
              row.append(agent)
           except:
              agent = 'agent:'
       if 'err' in sys.argv:
           try:
              errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
              row.append(errID)
           except:
              errID = 'ErrIdText:'
       if 'clear' in sys.argv:
           try:
              clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
              row.append(clear)
           except:
              clear = 'clearedID:'

       row = []
       data.append(row)

     for row in data:
        lines = o.writelines(row)
        print(row)

     o.close()
```

There is no error message but I want my output.txt file to break down line by line.

For example:
If the user run:

```
python export.py agent chassis
```

I expect the output.txt to print

```
['agent: 12367a12,', 'chassis:12367a12,']
['agent: 12368a15,', 'chassis:12368a15,']
```

But the output in the output.txt is:

```
agent:12367a12, chassis:12367a12, agent:12368a15, chassis:12368a15,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
for row in data:
    lines = o.writelines(row)
    lines = o.writelines("\n")
    print(row)
```

or

```
for row in data:
    row.append("\n")
    lines = o.writelines(row)
    print(row)
```

btw I am surprised that this code works ... because of you have defined row after you are using it

```
   // ( * )
   if something
       try:
          date = re.match(r'\date{2} \w+ \date{2}', line).group()
          row.append(date) // should crash
       except:
          date = 'date'
   if 'agent' in sys.argv:
       try:
          agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
          row.append(agent) // should crash
       except:
          agent = 'agent:'
   if 'err' in sys.argv:
       try:
          errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
          row.append(errID) // should crash
       except:
          errID = 'ErrIdText:'
   if 'clear' in sys.argv:
       try:
          clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
          row.append(clear) // should crash
       except:
          clear = 'clearedID:'

   row = [] // this should be defined where I put the star ( * )
   data.append(row) // always appends empty row ( [] )
```

Comment: @petelam np ^^ glad to be helpful

Comment: one quick follow up question @StyleZ; is there a way if I can add a command or space between each printed argument in my output.txt. Right now, if i run the argument to retrieve the "date, and agent" name. my output.txt would print out "19 May 19agent: 12367a12" I try adding comma and space but it only added to the end of the line, not the middle of the line. thanks

Comment: Yes, append it after each appending of s row :)

Comment: I tried adding "lines = o.writelines(",") but the comma would be print at the beginning of the line. not separating date and agent value

Comment: You have there 2x forloop ... in 1st forloop where you have data.append(row) add "," instead of row

Comment: that would make my print out to be just "," and no content from my log file

Comment: Add there another data.append() :D

Comment: that would just add a comma on the next line

Comment: Oh you have there all if's ( thought its just 1 if ) at the end of each appending add row.append(",")